# Save a two level multidimensional array to a csv file in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have an array that when printed with print_r looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Color
[Color] => Array
    (
        [0] => Red
        [1] => white
        [2] => Bleu
     )
[1] => size
[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => Small 
        [1] => Med 
        [2] => Large
     )
)
```

I am trying to dump it to a csv file that should look like this when finished:

Color: Red, White, Blue

size: Small, "1-1/2 Inch", "8 inch"

The code below gets part of the job done but I am having trouble getting the array keys to print out at the beginning of each line in the csv file. Thanks.

```
<?php

print_r($mf_url_array);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($mf_url_array));
foreach ($mf_url_array as $fields) {
    if(!empty($fields) and is_array($fields)){
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Your example array seems wrong, it can’t actually contain the key `0` twice. (And even if the second one was a `1`, why does this array have that structure, where do you get it from? The entries with numeric index holding the values `Color` and `size` seem kinda redundant, since those are the keys for the following arrays anyway.)

Comment: edit your comment with the output of var_export($you_array, true);

Comment: the array is just an example the actual array that is produced is way to big to post here but the structure is the same. Just changed the duplicate zero to make it a 1.